# How do I remove extra space from an embedded Sheets document?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Sheets document embedded on my website. For the most part it's great; most changes I make in the main document show up immediately on the embedded website version.

My issue is that there are instances where the edits I make in the main document don't show up in the embedded version. The worst is blank space in the rows. In the main document it looks perfect, but no matter what I try, there are always big gaps in the embedded iteration of the document.

I've tried eliminating the space on the main document and even gone to extreme lengths - e.g. beyond the point it even looks good in the main document - to see if it makes any difference in the embedded one. It doesn't. I also have done more than the requisite saves/reloads to make sure the embedded version has the latest info - it does, because other changes - not to do with the blank spaces - are immediately apparent.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Corbin

Comment: I invite you to share a link to the spreadsheet and to the web page. It's virtually impossible to make suggestions sight unseen.